# How to recieve number AND strings using only one io.read()?

Tags: lua

I want to do a program that tells the user if what kind of information is he telling...

that's what I have for now, but as you can see, it is missing the IF function to identify if it is a number, but I don't know how to get a number not using io.read('*number)

```
a = io.read()

if a == string.lower(a) then
  print('It's a lower string')
end

if a == string.upper(a) then 
  print('It's an upper string')
end
```

pls help

Comment: sorry for puting the code this way, it's not the way I initially wrote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep reading with `a = io.read()` and try to convert to a number:

```
a = io.read()
if tonumber(a) then
  print("It's a number")
elseif a == string.lower(a) then
  print("It's a lowercase string")
elseif a == string.upper(a) then
  print("It's an uppercase string")
end
```